# Найти самую длинную последовательность, состоящую из одинаковых символов при помощи Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Мне нужно в определенной строке найти самую длинную последовательность, состоящую из одинаковых символов используя только **Regular Expressions**. Возможно ли вообще это сделать?

Пример: *найти длину максимальной цепочки, состоящей из символов С*

```
string s = "AACCCCJDKSJKACCCCCK";
int max  = // TODO: some code
Console.WriteLine(max); //5
```

Comment: `только Regular Expressions` задание такое?

Comment: Да, нужно сделать без использования подобного: 
            `string s = "AACCCCJDKSJKACCCCCK";

            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                max = Math.Max(s[i..].TakeWhile(x => x == 'C').Count(), max);

            Console.WriteLine(max);`

Comment: добавьте пример вашей реализации, как вы пытались это сделать

Comment: А я бы как раз сделал без использования регэкспов, ибо вычислительная сложность будет намного ниже чем у регулярок. Да и с регулярками непонятно, как их сюда применить.

Comment: @Darth KYL, в том то и дело, что не знаю как это реализовать  в регулярных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "AACCCCJDKSJKACCCCCK";
    var sequences = Regex.Matches(text, @"(\w)\1*").Select(m => m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sequences.Select((x, i) => $"{i}: {x}")));
    int max = sequences.Select(x => x.Length).Max();
    Console.WriteLine($"Max: {max}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
0: AA
1: CCCC
2: J
3: D
4: K
5: S
6: J
7: K
8: A
9: CCCCC
10: K
Max: 5
```

Ну а если прямо ответить без демонстрации, то

```cs
int max = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w)\1*").Select(m => m.Value.Length).Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить следующее:

```
string s = "AACCCCJDKSJKACCCCCK";
int max = 0;
var regex = new Regex(@"(.)\1*");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(s))
{                
    if (max < match.Value.Length)
        max = match.Value.Length;
}

Console.WriteLine(max); //5
```

Используем [группировку с обратной связью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C).

`(.)` - группа, находящая один любой символ
`\1`  - совпадение с ранее найденной группой под номером 1
`*`   - любое количество раз

Никаких особых преимуществ от использования регулярок тут нет. Всё равно приходится использовать цикл.